# Mongodb findOne doesn't work

Tags: mongodb

I'm using for the first time a Mongodb and I got a very weird bug.. I have a 'games' collection and I can't make a search with _id query on it..

I try directly on the mongo shell and this is the result :

```
> db.games.count()
0
> db.games.insert({created:'ok'})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.games.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54f7364d1f2f9378d7a5ddde"), "created" : "ok" }
> db.games.findOne({_id:'54f7364d1f2f9378d7a5ddde'})
null
> db.games.find({_id:'54f7364d1f2f9378d7a5ddde'})
>
```

I really don't know what is going on ? I was thinking about a weird index on _id but I found nothing..

```
> db.games.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "cobra.games"
    }
]
>
```

This can maybe help you

```
> db.version()
2.6.5
```

Someone have an idea ?

Comment: Maybe try db.collection.find({"_id" : ObjectId("54f7364d1f2f9378d7a5ddde")})

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try:

```
db.games.find({"_id" : ObjectId("54f7364d1f2f9378d7a5ddde")})
```

The type of the data stored in the key `_id` is of `ObjectId` and your were searching for a String. So you the types were not matching. MongoDB has not auto-casting of String to ObjectId. This Error can also happen if your store your numbers as a Long but in your query you enter an Integer.

Comment: An ObjectId is not a string; it's an ObjectId. 1234 != "1234", it's the same idea here. Remember that MongoDB stores [BSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/), not JSON, so there are more types available than in JSON.